# Django Allauth replace labels

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-allauth

I have the following form that `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` is pointing to

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name in self.fields.keys():
            print(field_name, self.fields[field_name].label)
```

I'm trying to replace the labels for each of the following fields: `username`, `email`, `password1` and `password2`. When the form is initiated, the following is printed.

```
   username Username
   email None
```

But the rendered form in my browsers shows all of the fields with their labels

```
Username*
E-mail*
Password*
Password (again)*
```

Why is it that only `username` and `email` are being printed, and why is `email` field label is `None` yet it shows just fine when it is rendered.

How would I be able to change the labels of all four fields?

Comment: what the output of `print(dir(self.fields['email']))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't that do on the form that's set on `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS`. That form is used as base class to the SignupForm from allauth. So you can't change any field because it doesn't exist on that form (only on the subclass). To do what you want you have to subclass the SignupForm from django allauth and use that as the real signup form which can be set like this:

```
# On settings
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'path.to.custom.singup.form'}
```

The custom signup form must inherit from the django allauth singup form like this:

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm    


class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # here you can change the fields
        self.fields['email'] = forms.EmailField(label='custom label')
```